# What would be the shape of the Gaussian surface if we want to calculate the electric field due a uniformly charged "finite" long straight wire?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, symmetry, gauss-law

I was troubling with the question  why we select a cylindrical Gaussian surface to calculate the electric field at an arbitrary point **P** due to an *infinitely* long straight uniformly charged wire which would give $$\mathbf{E} = \frac{\lambda}{2π\varepsilon_0r}\mathbf{\hat{n}}$$ where $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ is the radial vector in the plane normal to the wire passing through the point. Then I came across this image on the web which explains what would happen if we restricted the length of the wire to be finite:

[image]

According to this image we **would not** be  able to make the assumption that the electric field lines at the two ends of the wire are normal to the curved part of the Gaussian surface because they clearly aren't. Thus we took the wire to be *infinitely* long so that we can take **E** to be normal to the surface from each point on the wire.

But I really wish to know what happens if we restrict the length of the wire to be *finite*. Specifically, I want to know

1. the shape of the Gaussian surface we would have to choose so that we can calculate the approximate value of the electric field produced due by the uniformly charged finite wire at an arbitrary point away from it.
2. equation for calculating **E** for the same.

(I'm just a high schooler, so please pardon me if the question seems illogical or something)

Comment: Your first request is not clear at all. What is the "it" in "due to it"? On what surface do you want to calculate the field?

Comment: Sorry for the confusions. By 'it' I meant the uniformly charged finite wire I'm talking about. And I understand that I shouldn't have said "surface" when I actually meant "an arbitrary point from the wire". I hope it's clear now :/

Comment: Yes, it is clear. Unfortunately, you can't calculate the field by using Gauss' law for this case.

Comment: In text books Gauss' law is used to calculate the electric field of a few special, highly symmetric cases exactly. These cases then allow you to build intuition for more complex cases. For non-symmetric configurations you can't do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> the shape of the Gaussian surface we would have to choose so that we can calculate the approximate value of the electric field produced due to it at an arbitrary point on the surface.

Unfortunately, there is no such shape. Gauss' law always holds in EM, but it is only useful for calculating E fields in cases with a high degree of symmetry. Only if a source is very symmetric is it possible to take advantage of the symmetry through the careful selection of a Gaussian surface and thereby calculate the result.

With an infinite wire you have three symmetries. The first is the translational symmetry along the axis. This means that the field cannot be a function of $z$ (or more specifically it is constant in $z$). The next is the rotational symmetry about the axis. This means that the field cannot be a function of $\theta$ either, so it must be a function of $r$ only. The third symmetry is the symmetry under a 180 degree rotation about an axis perpendicular to the main axis. This means that the field cannot have any tangential components. With those symmetries we can conclude that the field is uniform on the sides of a cylinder and zero on the top and bottom.

With a finite wire you lose the first symmetry. So the field can also be a function of $z$. The 180 degree rotation tells us that the field must be an even function of $z$, but since it is not necessarily constant we don't get that it is zero.

In cases with insufficient symmetry, you have to solve Gauss' law as a differential equation. Either $$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$ or $$\nabla^2 \phi = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$$

Comment: I'm not sure there is no shape, but it is certainly *very hard* to find, and even if a shape could be found it's not clear it's worth the effort to find such a surface compared with just integration.

Comment: Symmetry is often the difference between a problem that can be solved in high school, and a problem that requires a PhD...

Answer (score 3):

The integral form of Gauss' law cannot be used with a finite wire. You've already found the reasons why.  There is not enough symmetry to be able to make the simplifying features such as requiring the electric field to be normal to the surface.  I'm fairly certain that the differential form of the law can be used, but it wouldn't be pretty.  I've not seen it done.

Answer (score 1):

1. To add to the above answers, Gauss law is still applicable.
   $$\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{S} = \frac{Q}{ \epsilon_o} $$
   In the most raw form, it just states that "electric field flux (over a [gaussian] surface) is charge enclosed."
   This is uncontested and true. But, the definition of gaussian surface for let's say a finite length cylinder would be difficult (not impossible) to the extent of being impractical. Symmetry makes it a lot easier. (Though, I would appreciate any following answer which achieves to do so; if it were so, I predict that the gaussian surface would probably look like a "capsule").
2. If still we were to find the electric field of this electrostatic system,
   then it is much more convenient to rely on the electric potential $V$.
   As in the undergraduate course, you will learn that an electrostatic field could be sufficiently defined by the scalar potential.
   $$\vec{E} = - \nabla V$$
   in naive terms, $$\vec{E} = - \frac{dV}{dr} \vec{r}$$
   This is a scalar function and we would not be fussing over the vectors as in case of electric field $\vec{E}$.
   How to find the electric potential $V$ then?

- One way could be the poisson's equation (cause why not?)
  $$\nabla^2V = -\frac{\lambda}{\epsilon_o} $$
  (I am myself not comfortable with solving diff equations).
- Other way is to integrate potential over localized charge distributions. $$V(r) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o} \int \frac{\lambda}{r-r_0} dl$$

Comment: I was also thinking about a capsule shaped Gaussian surface after reading the previous answers! but yeah, now I understand it would not be worth it.

Comment: On a second thought, you can definitely at the high-school level, calculate the electric field "at the mid point" of the finite length case.
Use Coulombs law and some Pythagoras theorem.
If you did, what insights would that shower?

What if you shift a little bit off of the mid point? 
Use section formula on the above find. 

How does the electric field change in the two cases?

Comment: I'm sorry. I lost. I was somewhere near getting the field at the midpoint to be smth like kq/r² + kΠ(1+½+⅓+....1/n) if r is negligible, where Π=linear charge density. I feel my finding is so incomplete. Can you share your thoughts?

Comment: Nothing to lose (than time). Of course, for completeness, we would require the (ugly) differential equations. We wanted insights.
Let's abstract the finite cylinder to line charge, for simplicity. Further, the charge density is uniform. Total charge is $\lambda L$; split evenly at midpoint it becomes $\frac {\lambda L}{2}$. Distance is $r = \sqrt{d^2 + h^2}$ 
(Let's neglect the effect of inv. sq law.) 
Upon shifting a bit off of the midpoint, this charge split gets disproportionate. There is more charge to one side of it. Unequal field.
Now see the image you provided. Field vector tilting.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it! Had this intuition, that it will turn out to be like this anyway ie. unequal as we go away from the midpoint (but I couldn't bear with those nasty differentials, just like you!)